# Not hidden slided items of array during animation in MDB Angular

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, mdbootstrap

During animations six of items come out from div as image below.

How to hide slided elements during animations.

**Using carousel from mdb for angular**

Internet's fail me or I can't find answers for my questions.

[image: slided cars]

HTML:

```
        <mdb-carousel class="carousel-multi-item multi-animation" [animation]="'slide'">
            <ng-template #thenBlock >
                <mdb-carousel-item *ngFor="let cards of slides; let i = index">
                    <li  class="search-car__display-link" *ngFor="let car of cards ; let i index" >
                        <a [routerLink]="['/car-detail', car.id]">
                            <car-card [car]="i"></car-card>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </mdb-carousel-item>
            </ng-template>
        </mdb-carousel>
```

SCSS:

```
.search-car {
    &__display-results {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    &__display-link {
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style: none;
        

        & > a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    }
}
.carousel-item {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
    &.active, &.carousel-item-right, &.carousel-item-next {
      display: flex !important;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      z-index: 2;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIX!**

Edit some HTML structure, deleting ng-templates with ng-container not added in issue. It's work on this code.

```
<mdb-carousel @displayFilteredCars [isControls]="true" class="carousel-multi-item multi-animation" [animation]="'slide'">
                <mdb-slide *ngFor="let cards of slides; let i = index">
                    <li  class="search-car__display-link" *ngFor="let car of cards ; let i index" >
                        <a [routerLink]="['/car-detail', car.id]">
                            <car-card [car]="i"></car-card>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </mdb-slide>
</mdb-carousel>
```